# Multiple Alarms at Same Time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have time let's say 01:01 am,now i want to trigger two notifications first is five minutes before the time and second is two minutes before the time. Here's the code I have done so far for this :

```
    fun setAlarm() {

   val time: String = "01:01 AM"
            val inFormat3 = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm")
            val date = inFormat3.parse(time)
            Log.e("Timeis",date.minutes.toString() + " " + date.hours)
         //   val df = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")
          /*  val d = df.format(date)*/
            val calNow = Calendar.getInstance()
            val calSet = calNow.clone() as Calendar
            val calSet2 = calNow.clone() as Calendar

           // val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
            calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, date.hours)
            calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, date.minutes)
            calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
            calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0)
            calSet2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, date.hours)
            calSet2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, date.minutes)
            calSet2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
            calSet2.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0)

            calSet.add(Calendar.MINUTE,-5)
            calSet2.add(Calendar.MINUTE,-2)

            if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
                //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }
            if(calSet2.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
                //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                calSet2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }


            val intent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("NotificationText", "some text")
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            val PendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,2,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            val alarmManager = this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
            val alarmManager2 =  this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000,pendingIntent)
            alarmManager2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calSet2.getTimeInMillis(),24*60*60*1000,PendingIntent2)
}
```

Now it is only triggering notfification before 5 minutes but not 2 minutes before notification. What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try removing the first notification and see if the second one comes again or not

Comment: also it might just be a weird coincidence but your `PendingIntent2` is blue and capitalized. Try to set that to lowercase. I doubt that will do anything but it just looks so weird considering things in blue are Android Classes

Comment: Hey @Pavneet_Singh I did remove the first notification but still second one is not coming.

Comment: @cjnash second one is coming but it is updating the firstone,how can i stop it?

Comment: What do you mean by your last comment "second one is coming but it is updating first one"?